# chrome.storage.sync.set not working in unload event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I've been working on a small Chrome extension and I want to save some stuff to storage whenever the popup closes.

```
addEventListener("unload", function () {
    var background = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
    chrome.storage.sync.set({"test": [1,2,3]}, function() {
        background.console.log("working");
    });
    background.updateStorage();
}, true);
```

The `updateStorage` function call from the background page works fine, however the `storage.sync.set` doesn't and I'm not sure why. I've tried the same code in other event listeners, and they all seem to work fine. Is this a problem with unload? Or am I missing something else here?

Comment: I would assume `unload` returns and the popup closes before `set` finishes its work.  Could you temporarily prevent the unloading?

Comment: I don't believe unload events are honored in Chrome extensions. You will probably have to periodically save automatically.